# Can I get the value of serverTimestamp before saving to Firestore?

Tags: timestamp, google-cloud-firestore, querying

I need to save a timestamp to firebase in the Unix Epoch format `12554327536` where it's milliseconds since epoch. I DON'T want to use `Date().valueOf()` because that isn't accurate if the system time is wrong. I also can't store it as the default `December 25, 2020 at 12:02:50 PM UTC-5` because I need to use firebase's querying to sort by date. I'm using it like this:

```
ref.where(`users.${userAuth.uid}`, '>', 0)
   .orderBy(`users.${userAuth.uid}`)
```

I am thinking if I get the value first, then convert it, then save it. I can then search and sort this way... Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Do you need something like this : `firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` ?

Comment: Something like that maybe, but this returns `{.sv: "timestamp"}`

Comment: I just checked, Its works but do not console try to save this to your database. Its a function instead a value! at my app I used : `firebase.database().ref('users/'+this.user.uid +'/lastLogged').set(firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);` //(new Date()).getTime()

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get the actual **server-side** timestamp before the data is written on the server.

But there is work under way to expose a client-side estimate of the timestamp before the data is committed. See https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/pull/537

Comment: how can i do this on android?